# Rails + Mongoid - Don't return nil values in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a lot of optional fields in Mongoid, like:

```
  field :key, type: String             
  field :element, type: String         
  field :rect, type: Array
```

If I return a json of this model with only one of them filled I get `null` values on all the other fields. How can I remove those fields?

My model has nested attributes, which means null values can be on several levels.

**Clarifications:**

I need a way to remove null fields from the json representation of a model, including null fields in all nested attributes.

**Code Example**:

```
1.9.3-p0 :005 > u=Muse.new(:key=>'ram').to_json
 => "{\"_id\":\"4f1ced749c2ee4219d000003\",\"element\":null,\"key\":\"ram\",\"rect\":null}"
```

Comment: Some example data / expected inputs/outputs would be helpful here

Comment: It works fine when calling to_json on model. the json object doesnt have any empty fields? Which version of mongoid you are using? and is it return null on calling your_doc_obj.to_json?

Comment: it DOES have empty fields. only one of the fields in the example is populated, the other are nulls, I want to strip them out. I also want to strip out other fields (but those I'll strip with :attr_protected)

Comment: @myxospsm, you have to use `Muse.new(:key=>'ram').as_json.reject! {|k,v| v.nil?}` instead `Muse.new(:key=>'ram').to_json` to get the correct results. Thats what i said in my answer. please run `Muse.new(:key=>'ram').as_json.reject! {|k,v| v.nil?}` and let me know what you got...

Comment: Yeah, obviously it works (though I'll have to write a function for nested attributes) but it stil is kinda lame, I was hoping for a cleaner way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `mongoid` has the ability to remove empty fields. If you  let some fields empty, `mongoid` will removes them on insert.

in the below example, I left out the fields element & rect

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

    field :key, type: String             
    field :element, type: String         
    field :rect, type: Array       

    embeds_one :home  
end
>> u=User.new(:key=>'ram').to_json
=> "{"_id":"4f1c3722b356f82e4a000001","_type":"key":"ram"}"
```

and it works perfectly. But if you put a nil value in the field

```
>> u=User.new(:key=>'ram',:element=>nil).to_json
=> "{"_id":"4f1c3722b356f82e4a000001","_type":"User","key":"ram","element":null}"
```

It gets inserted. I assume that's the exact problem in your code. So you can work around this by converting JSON hash representation using `as_json` and remove the nil fields

```
x=u.as_json.reject! {|k,v| v.nil?}
=> "{"_id":"4f1c3722b356f82e4a000001","_type":"User","key":"ram"}"
```

But to go to the inner levels, you cannot use `as_json`. check the below code

```
  >>h=Home.new(:address=>'xxxx',:dummy=>nil)
  >>u.home = h 
  >>x=u.as_json.reject! {|k,v| v.nil?}
  =>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f1c39b4b356f82e4a000003'), "_type"=>"User","key":"ram","home"=>#<Home _id: 4f1c3c5db356f82e4a000004,address:'xxxx' , dummy: nil >}
```

Now you see the field dummy inside the embedded doc house is still with nil. so my best advice is **Dont put the nil values in db at all**. To do that put a `before_save` callback on your models (embedded too) and remove the empty fields.

Also I will show you how to remove nil fields from nested objects too. Use it if there is no other way

We can  use `attributes` of  mongoid model to get the hash representation of the object including the nested levels

```
x=u.attributes
=> {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId4f1c39b4b356f82e4a000003,"key"=>"ram","element"=>nil,"home"=>{"address"=>"xxxx", "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId4f1c3c5db356f82e4a000004,"dummy"=>nil}}
```

and you have to find is there any Hash inside the mongoid object, if one, we have to use the `reject! {|k,v| v.nil?}` on that Hash too

to put together all

```
def to_json(obj)
     obj.reject! {|k,v| v.nil?}
     obj.find_all {|x| x[1].class==BSON::OrderedHash}.each do |arr| 
           obj[arr[0]] = to_json(arr[1])    
     end
     obj     
end
```

and call this with attributes of the model,

```
 >> to_json u.attributes
 => {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId4f1c39b4b356f82e4a000003,"key"=>"ram","home"=>{"address"=>"xxxx", "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId4f1c3c5db356f82e4a000004}}
```

Thats all. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! it sounds reasonable, the recursive hash thingy is what I eventually did but it sucks and I put up the bounty to find another way. I'll test it tomorrow but this line seems wrong: ""{"_id":"4f1c3722b356f82e4a000001","_type":"key","fname":"ram"}"" - what's fname?

Comment: @myxospsm, thats a typo... i mixed up with my original test data :(

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. Mongoid automatically puts null values inside the model. Maybe I'll use dynamic fields. (example out is in the question)

Comment: Which version of mongoid you are using? because my examples were from mongoid 2.2.4. But thats not a problem here. did you run my custom to_json method? what did you get? still null values. please run that and add the results..  i believe it should work irrespective of the mongoid version

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to remove field keys with nil values from query results before sending JSON, say, to the browser, you can simply do this (works in my case):

```
doc = Model.all.entries.map {|d| d.as_document}
respond_width(doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no such feature in the Mongoid iself.
My suggestion would be to go with one of the API generators then:

http://fabrik42.github.com/acts_as_api/

https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

or

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: I've looked at acts_as_api before, but I don't see how it solves the null removal problem.

Comment: You basically have some business rules for composing the JSON response. So, unless you want to code it by hand (which is surely possible), you're better off using one of these solutions, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do if you're using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) (check out [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers) for a quick intro).

For your use case, you can write a `muse_serializer.rb` that looks like this:

```rb
class MuseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def attributes
    muse = super
    object.attributes.each do |attr|
      muse[attr[0]] = attr[1]
    end
    muse.delete('_id') #in case you want to exclude the _id field
    muse
  end
end
```

This will return all non-empty fields present in the current Muse object.