# Calling .attributes on model object avoid fileds with nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

When `attributes()` is called on a `Mongoid` model object it excludes the fields with `nil` values, is there a way to get all the fields irrespective of their values?

```
media = Media.first
media.attributes #=> ignores nil values
```

Also, FYI this happens when a record is created with only a few attributes, but when we create a record by assigning `nil` values to the remaining fields explicitly it works fine!

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can have callback like before_save to assign remaining attributes as nil. This is the default property of mongoid to skip missed attributes

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8963019/10522579) may help in details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongoid` used to remove empty fields. If you kept some fields empty on insert, `mongoid` will removes them.

Use `media.to_json` instead for your case.

Comment: Right, to_json returns all the attributes! Thanks for the workaround!

Comment: `as_json` works even better, it returns a hash just like `attributes` with all the fields!